# Pandas apply Rank to a single group only

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Consider the below dataframe and output of the sum of total sales.

I would like to rank the output for all sub-groups and not overall. Desired output below.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate df
np.random.seed(0)
list_dfs = []
for _ in range(2):
    list_dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(
                    list(itertools.product(['audio', 'computers', 'video'], [2007, 2008, 2019])),
                    columns = ['category', 'year']))       

new_df = pd.concat(list_dfs).assign(total_sale = np.random.randint(0,10000, len(new_df))).reset_index(drop=True)
new_df.groupby(['category', 'year'])['total_sale'].sum()

# output
"""
category   year
audio      2007     6200
           2008    10550
           2019     5863
computers  2007     7081
           2008    16993
           2019    10788
video      2007    14266
           2008     6411
           2019    12960
"""
# desired output with rank()
"""
category   year
audio      2007     2.0
           2008     1.0
           2019     3.0
computers  2007     3.0
           2008     1.0
           2019     2.0
video      2007     1.0
           2008     3.0
           2019     2.0
"""
```

pandas version -> 0.25.0

python -> 3.8

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
year_rank = lambda df: df.groupby(['year'])['total_sale'].sum().rank(ascending=False)
output = new_df.groupby(['category']).apply(year_rank).stack()
```

Comment: I like your answer. But use `rank(ascending = False)` to get the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can group your current dataframe by category, i.e. the first level of its index. Then, you can compute the ranks in each category:

```
new_df_sum = new_df.groupby(['category', 'year'])['total_sale'].sum()
new_df_sum.groupby(new_df_sum.index.get_level_values(0)).apply(lambda x: x.rank(ascending = False))
```

As the highest total sale is supposed to have the rank 1, use `ascending = False`